# Jupyterhub - ERROR:asyncio:Task exception was never retrieved

Tags: python, jupyterhub, python-asyncio

I'm not able to install Jupyterhub using pip. I tried reinstall, but no matter what, I'm still getting asyncio Error.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong ?

```
[root@localhost bin]# which python3
/usr/bin/python3
[root@localhost bin]# which python
/usr/bin/python
[root@localhost bin]# python3 -V
Python 3.6.8
[root@localhost bin]# python -V
Python 2.7.5
```

So I'm installing JH using pip, I omitted most of requirements

```
[root@localhost bin]# pip3 install jupyterhub
WARNING: Running pip install with root privileges is generally not a good idea. Try `pip3 install --user` instead.
Collecting jupyterhub
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0d/67/c1e7d691bcb635fcde61c544d8fbca1edebb7bb4f68f34f5de291eba02d0/jupyterhub-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: prometheus-client>=0.0.21 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from jupyterhub)
Requirement already satisfied: alembic in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from jupyterhub)
. 
. 
. 
Requirement already satisfied: cffi!=1.11.3,>=1.8 in /usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages (from cryptography>=2.8->pyopenssl->certipy>=0.1.2->jupyterhub)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from cffi!=1.11.3,>=1.8->cryptography>=2.8->pyopenssl->certipy>=0.1.2->jupyterhub)
Installing collected packages: jupyterhub
Successfully installed jupyterhub-1.0.0
```

configurable proxy is already installed

```
[root@localhost bin]# configurable-http-proxy -V
4.2.0
```

but still no progress from Jupyterhub

```
[root@localhost bin]# jupyterhub -V
1.0.0
ERROR:asyncio:Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished coro=<JupyterHub.launch_instance_async() done, defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyterhub/app.py:2477> exception=SystemExit(0,)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyterhub/app.py", line 2492, in launch_instance
    loop.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 148, in start
    self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 438, in run_forever
    self._run_once()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1451, in _run_once
    handle._run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/asyncio/events.py", line 145, in _run
    self._callback(*self._args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyterhub/app.py", line 2479, in launch_instance_async
    await self.initialize(argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyterhub/app.py", line 2085, in initialize
    super().initialize(*args, **kwargs)
  File "</usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/decorator.py:decorator-gen-2>", line 2, in initialize
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 297, in initialize
    self.parse_command_line(argv)
  File "</usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/decorator.py:decorator-gen-4>", line 2, in parse_command_line
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 532, in parse_command_line
    self.exit(0)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 654, in exit
    sys.exit(exit_status)
SystemExit: 0
[root@localhost bin]#
```

Answer (score -1):

does you python env includes jupyterlab? pip install jupyterlab.

Comment: I recommend against rhetoric questions in answers. They risk being misunderstood as not an answer at all. You are trying to answer the question at the top of this page, aren't you? Otherwise please delete this post.

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."

Comment: Would installing be all that is needed to solve the problem? No need to actually use it in any way?